# Can't access to a iSCSI volume

Tags: linux, iscsi

I have a iSCSI target on a customer place I'm using from an old Fedora (Core6) server. I configured it and formatted as ext3 (mistake, now I know) and I've been working with it for some time.

Now I need to access this volume from other machine. As far as I've read, I can't do it safely  from two machines at the same time (yep, that's the first thing I tried). So I've umount it from original server and tried to mount it on the new server (I did it at first with Ubuntu 10 LTS but when I was unable to do it I installed another Fedora with the same configuration) with no success.

The problem: I can see all target on NAS but when I do a "fdisk -l" to see all devices and know which mount I see all targets as SFS filesystem. From the original server I see all SFS (after all, they belong to my customer and don't know what he have in) except the one I manage which I see as 'Linux'.

Here it is the partition table as seen in the server (Fedora) which see it right. Spanish language, sorry. I hope it can be understood. My comments between [...]

```
[.. at beginning the real local drive ..]

Disco /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cilindros of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000080

Disposit. Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sda1               1          26      204800   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              26        6400    51200000   83  Linux
[.. more local partitions ..]

[... then iSCSI drives ...]

Disposit. Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sdc1               1      130541  1048570551   42  SFS

Disco /dev/sdf: 2147.5 GB, 2147483649024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 261083 cylinders 
Units = cilindros of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2257d76f


[..... Other devices in between, and here it is the one I mind .....]

Disco /dev/sde: 2147.5 GB, 2147483648000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 261083 cylinders 
Units = cilindros of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 262144 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0x93afd446

Disposit. Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sde1               1      261083  2097149166   83  Linux  


[ .... and ever more devices ....]
```

On the machine I'm trying to configure, the one which should access the drive (but don't) I see the offending target as:

```
[....]

Disk /dev/sdc: 2147.4 GB, 2147483649024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 261083 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1      261083  2097149166   42  SFS


[....]
```

And I see rest of targets as SFS, the same as in first case.

Thank you in advanced,

Comment: Please post the output from `fdisk -l` so that we could see that the target in question is not visible. What's your iSCSI target? Am I correct that Fedora is an initiator in terms of iSCSI topology and the target is exported by some other device?

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I've just add the **fdisk -l** output on both machines. And right: Old Fedora (whoch works) and new Ubuntu (don't work) and both initiators. Targets are on a NAS device but don't know the brand and model but almost sure a QNap. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

fdisk reported labels don't mean much nowadays -- in fact as MS-DOS partition tables fall out of use, it even can be entirely misleading. If you want to know what's on a partition, better use `file -s /dev/sdXX`:

```
 file -s /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=ebf12615-9c1a-4aca-9111-bebd1eaf4ed3 (large files)
file -s /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=7322a490-8814-4f0b-92a7-a6f4287acadc (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

Comment: Didn't knew that, thank you wazoox for your info. Anyway, I can't access iSCSI target as **file** command reports it as 'data'  so cannot mount it. Any hint?

Comment: @jmiguel.rodriguez, this is definitely strange. What are you exporting from the iSCSI target? is it a fileIO or a blockIO device? You should give more details on the target type (lio, iet, tgt; etc) and configuration.

Comment: I never knew about `file -s`...  That would have come in handy recently!  My current method of discovering the file system is with `blkid`.  eg. `/dev/sda1: UUID="c7f00876-a631-41c4-bf78-4cd18cce4041" TYPE="ext3"`

Comment: Well, "file" has the advantage of working for about anything, block devices, media files, etc :)

Answer (score 1):

SFS (0x42) partition type in fdisk -l output may be a sign of a partition that existed before it was formatted as ext3.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#List_of_partition_IDs) this partition type may correspond to Windows 2000/XP dynamic volume. If the partition was simply reformatted as EXT3, the type code could be left unchanged.

In order to check what partition type is there you could issue

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp --tmpdir=/tmp) 
dd if=/dev/sdc1 bs=512 count=2048 of=$TMPFILE
file $TMPFILE
rm $TMPFILE
```

on a ext4 filesystem, for example, this sequence would produce

```
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.0291348 s, 36.0 MB/s
/tmp/tmp.QLD5XhZOYn: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data (needs journal recovery)
(extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

That indicates that whatever the partition type specified in the partition table, the partition itself is an EXT4. One Megabyte is usually enough to identify the true partition type.

If `/dev/sdc1` indeed is an EXT3 partition as you expect, you could mount it safely. I would suggest though to mount it via Device Mapper `multipath` mount point to avoid problems if the device enumeration over iSCSI changes.

Comment: Good point. Thank you. I've tested it, and on first machine (where it's well mounted):

[root@scancia ~]# file /tmp/test 
/tmp/test: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)

On second machine (SFS system):
[root@scanciaprodj2ee ~]# file /tmp/test 
/tmp/test: data

So.. bad news. :-(

I'll look the multipath parameter you mention, I presume it will solve the problem I also have (althouth didn't mind a lot) with /dev/sd?1 names on every reboot.